# How can I use a textview to navigate to another activity?

Tags: java, android

My app has stopped responding to adding `setOnClickListener` event.

```
e3 = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.register );
e3.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) { 
        Intent move=new Intent( MainActivity.this,registration.class );
        startActivity( move );
    }
} );
```

Can anybody help me? Thanks.

Comment: can you provide stack trace?

Comment: Whats the message it displayed in Logcat ?

Comment: You must mention each activity in android manifest.

Comment: Are You Sure You Have Added The Activity In Manifest And The registration class is extending an Activity or AppCompatActivity

Comment: Please share your logcat.

Answer (score 0):

I think there may two reasons for this. This Is Guess On Your Posted Code......
At First To Know exact reason add stack trace on your post.
But Now check these two reasons :
1) Check If The Name Of Both Activities For Which you are requesting an intent.
2) If activity names are correct ; check that activity is present in Your application manifest.

PS -- Activity Name For Which Your Are Providing Intent Is Registration.class ; Check If This Is Correct Or Not. I feel that it is incorrect.